# Displaying a matrix with integral entries

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I have a matrix nxn with coefficients a[i,j] like:

```
a[i,j]=NIntegrate[T[r], {r, -le, le}] - NIntegrate[T[r] Abs[r]/le, {r, -le, le}]
```

I can solve the matrix but I want to know if there is a method to show the matrix simbolically before the solve. Then I don't want to see only the end solution but even the composition of the matrix with the integrals for extended. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? I don't see any equation!

Comment: Are all entries equal?

Comment: no, the a[i,j] are different. I posted here only a term . for "solve" I mean that I don't want that mathematica solves the Nintegral in the coefficient. At the end I obtain a matrix like: [{1,3,5},{3,1,4},{5,4,1}]. but i want to see the matrix composed by integral

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to have to write a separate function that uses `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` if you want something that looks like a matrix of traditional integrals, which is what I think you want. You also need to use `HoldForm` to keep the integral from evaluating. You also need someway to set the values that you want in the held version of the expression. I've used `With`, someone else may have a better idea. Without this you'll get the symbol used as the table iterator in your integral.

```
Table[
  With[{f = i, g = j},
   HoldForm@Integrate[x, {x, f, g}]]
  , {i, 1, 4}
  , {j, 1, 4}
  ] // MatrixForm
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: thank you!!!! this is what i was looking for!

Comment: What I have noticed is `m.n` would "work" to produce a meaningful result for matrices `m` and `n` but `m//MatrixForm . n//MatrixForm` does not compute.  This would seem to be not explicit in the documentation?

Comment: `MatrixForm` is a formatting function that produces readable output. You don't want to do calculations on lists that you've applied `MatrixForm` to.

Comment: @diana since this answer seems to solve your problem, you might want to accept it by clicking on the gray check mark next to it.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you I dind't know it!